# Light refraction in a glass sphere: Is there a focus or not?

Tags: visible-light, refraction, lenses

Recently, someone told me to pay attention when hanging a wind chime containing a glass sphere in front of the window, because a focus point might be formed on the curtains which might on a sunny day set the curtains on fire.

To my intuition, this seemed wrong, but I am unsure if my intuitive feeling is correct.

I know that because of the fundamental property of a sphere/circle, any light ray going through its center will pass through unrefracted.

Also, I read about [Spherical Abberation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_aberration), which seems to indicate that (at least parallel) light rays will not end up in the same focus point.

I believe that incoming rays of sunlight are usually considered to be parallel.

Is this enough to say that burning your curtains by having sunlight pass through a glass sphere is highly unlikely, or not?

A more formal explanation of why a burning point might (or cannot) be formed in this scenario would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A shoemaker glass sphere was used in the past to concentrate the light of candles to the working place of the shoemaker.   -   Drawing the ingoing and outgoing rays of the sphere one can see that there is a concentration towards the center line and not a point. BUT having a huge enough sphere and a powerful light source it would be possible to burn something.

Comment: It is certainly in the realm of the physically possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend is right!  Here's [an unfortunate example](http://www.seattletimes.com/seattle-news/dogs-water-bowl-may-be-cause-of-fire-in-bellevue/).

To elaborate a bit, you're right, if the surfaces of a lens are not parabolic but spherical, the focal point will be diffused somewhat, but you nevertheless get a high amount of concentration of the incoming energy.  At the focal plane the light coming in across the entire diameter of the sphere will be concentrated down to a circle of much smaller area, increasing the intensity if the incoming sunlight in inverse proportion to the cross-sectional area, enough to start a fire.

Answer (score 2):

Ball lenses work just fine (http://www.edmundoptics.com/resources/application-notes/optics/understanding-ball-lenses/). In ordinary lenses, light rays going through the optical center of the lens are not deflected either. Ordinary lenses also have spherical aberrations. I don't have a ball lens at home, but I am pretty sure one can start a fire using such a lens. See also https://www.exploratorium.edu/snacks/water-sphere-lens